# Find the last two digits of the number $9^{9^9}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find the last two digits of the number $9^{9^9}$ .

[Hint: $9^9 \equiv 9 \pmod {10} $; hence, $9^{9^9}$ = $9^9+10k$ ;now use the fact that $9^9 \equiv 89 \pmod {100}$]

Comment: Do you mean $9\uparrow(9\uparrow9)=9^{9^9}$ or $(9\uparrow9)\uparrow9=(9^9)^9$? Parentheses aren't optional here.

Comment: there are no parentheses

Comment: @DavidH He means, $9^{9^9}$ I *think*

Comment: @Lil Yes, and you should fix that.

Comment: @Sabyasachi I guessed that too. But I firmly believe pedantry is a virtue in mathematics. ;)

Comment: @DavidH I agree.

Comment: Lil, why do you want solutions to old homework problems?  (This problem is from [here](http://pat-rossi.com/MTH4436/homework/p_73_1.pdf)).

Comment: Also, [Find the last two digits of 9^(9^9)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657131/find-the-last-two-digits-of-999?rq=1)

Answer (score 5):

Our observations start like this;

$9=-1 ($mod $10) \Rightarrow 9^9=(-1)^9 ($mod $10)$ or $9^9=-1 $(mod $10)$ 
We have  $-1=9 ($mod $10)$, thus $9^9=9 ($mod $10)$    ...i

This statement directly implies that upon dividing $9^9$ by $10$ we get a remainder $9$.Thus $9^9=9+10k$

Also,$9^9=89 ($mod $100) \Rightarrow 9*9^9=9*89 ($mod $100)$
or $9^{10}=801($mod $100)$. Also, $801=1 ($mod $100)$ thus making
$9^{10} = 1 \pmod{100}$       ....ii

$(9^{10})^k=1^k ($mod $100)$   from ii
$9^9*(9^{10})^k=9^9 ($mod $100)$ or, $9^{(9+10k)}=9^9 ($mod $100)$. Since,$9^9=89 ($mod $100)$, we have $9^{(9+10k)}=89 ($mod $100)$
This statement implies that upon division of $9^{9^9}$ by $100$ we get a remainder of $89$. Thus last two digits are $89$.

Answer (score 3):

$$9^{9^9}=(10-1)^{9^9}\equiv(-1)^{9^9}+9^9\cdot10^1\cdot(-1)^{9^9-1}\equiv-1+10\cdot9^9\pmod{100}$$

Now, $\displaystyle9^9=(10-1)^9\equiv-1\pmod{10}\implies10\cdot9^9\equiv-10\pmod{10\cdot10}$

$$\implies9^{9^9}\equiv-1-10\pmod{100}\equiv100-11$$

Comment: Minor typo in first line: Should be $\equiv -1 \color{green}{+} 10 \cdot 9^9 (\text{mod } 100)$.