# Finding the last two digits of $9^{9^{9^{…{^9}}}}$ (nine 9s)

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm continuing on my journey learning about modular arithmetic and got confused with this question:

Find the last two digits of $9^{9^{9^{…{^9}}}}$ (nine 9s). The phi function is supposed to be used in this problem and so far this is what I've got:

$9^{9^{9^{…{^9}}}} ≡ x (\text{mod } 100)$
Where $0 ≤ x ≤ 100$

$9^{9^{9^{…{^9}}}} \text{ (nine 9s) }= 9^a$
In order to know $9^a (\text{mod } 100)$, we need to know $a (\text{mod } \phi(100))$
As $\phi(100)= 40$, we get $a = b (\text{mod } 40)$

$9^{9^{9^{…{^9}}}} \text{ (eight 9s) }= 9^b$
In order to know $9^b (\text{mod } 40)$, we need to know $b (\text{mod } \phi(40))$
As $\phi(40)= 16$, we get $b = c ( \text{mod }16)$

$9^{9^{9^{…{^9}}}}\text{ (seven 9s) }= 9^c $
In order to know $9^c (mod 16)$, we need to know $c (\text{mod } phi(16))$
as $\phi(16)= 8 $ we need to find $c (\text{mod } 8)$

As $9 = 1 (\text{mod } 8)$
$c = 1 (\text{mod } 8)$

I feel like I might have made a mistake somewhere along the way because I'm having a lot of trouble stitching it all back together in order to get a value for the last two digits. Could anyone please help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742341/find-the-last-two-digits-of-the-number-999).

Comment: Minor variant of [The last two digits of $9^{9^9}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65454/the-last-two-digits-of-999)

Comment: [Last few digits of $n^{n^{n^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot^n}}}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166083/last-few-digits-of-nnn-cdot-cdot-cdotn?noredirect=1&lq=) is a better one

Comment: I'll check these two out! Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Consider $a_n=9^{9^{2n+1}}$ and show by induction that $a_n\equiv 89\pmod{100}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

By the binomial theorem, we have that 
$$a_0=9^9=(10-1)^9\equiv 9\cdot 10^1 (-1)^8 +(-1)^9=90-1=89\pmod{100}.$$ 
Moreover, for $n\geq 0$,
$$a_{n+1}=9^{81\cdot 9^{2n+1}}=a_n^{81}\equiv 89^{81}\equiv ?\pmod{100}$$
Can you take it from here? (you already noted that $\varphi(100)=40$).

Comment: Got the answer! Thank you very much!