# Find last three digits of $8^{8^8}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, tetration

I am attempting to find $8^{8^8}$ (which, by the way, means $8^{(8^8)}$) without any means such as computers/spreadsheets. Here's my attempt so far, and I'm pretty sure my answer is correct, but I would like a more efficient method.

First, I do the exponent: $8^8=(2^3)^8=2^{24}$, and I calculated that the last three digits are 216 by hand. I then know that $8^{(8^8)}\equiv8^{216} \pmod{1000}$, and so I have to calculate this and found that it repeats in cycles of $100$.

[image]

Using this information, I deduce that $8^{(8^8)}\equiv8^{216}\equiv8^{200}\cdot8^{16}\equiv8^{16}\equiv2^{48}\equiv656\pmod{1000}$

Is there is a more efficient way to solve this problem than just listing out all the remainders, as I have done? I would like to keep the explanation as basic as possible, without such devices as Euler's totient function, etc.

Someone has asked me if [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand) is what I wanted, but no, because I want to keep it as elementary as possible, and I also don't want any tedious calculations (as I have done).

Comment: Using modulo of exponents is not valid. For example, $7 \equiv 2 \pmod 5$, but $2^7 = 128 \equiv 3 \pmod 5$ while $2^2 = 4 \equiv 4 \pmod 5.$

Comment: I don't think this deserves a downvote. There's clearly a lot of effort.

Comment: If you insist on using brute force cycle determination then it would be better pedagogically to choose an example with period smaller than $100$.

Comment: Generally the quickest way to do problems this is using the **mod Distributive Law** [as here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3161162/242). But that involves a little number theory.

Comment: It can be done easily by the first few terms of the Binomial Theorem without requiring any periodicity knowledge. If that is of interest let me know and I will post the details

Comment: @BillDubuque Yes please post your answer. Thank you!

Comment: @KingLogic Ok, posted. There are probably further simplifications that can be had, but I haven't had a chance to think much about it. That's already very simple (I can do it mentally).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Not really because I desire a method without the totient function or Chinese remainder theorem, etc. I would like an extremely elementary method, to teach to high school students with very little background in number theory.

Comment: Alright. Still going to leave the link though, as it is probably useful to someone else.

Comment: @KingLogic I added the mDL apporach to my answer when someone requested further details. You might find that of further interest.

Comment: Note that you know that the answer will be divisible by $8$ so you are only really interested modulo $125$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without Euler's totient function, by repeated squaring, from $8^8\equiv216\bmod1000$,

we have $8^{16}\equiv656\bmod1000$, $8^{32}\equiv336\bmod1000$, $8^{64}\equiv896\bmod1000$,

and $8^{128}\equiv816\bmod 1000$, so $8^{216}\equiv8^{128}8^{64}8^{16}8^8\equiv656\bmod1000.$

And I would like to re-iterate the comment that $c^a\equiv c^b\bmod n$

does not generally follow from $a\equiv b\bmod n$.

Comment: That's a lot of painful mod $1000$ multiplications that are  left for the reader!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using only simple mod arithmetic and $\,\rm\color{#90f}{BT}=$ Binomial Theorem

Let $\ N := (8^{\large 8}\!-\!2)/2 \equiv -18\,\pmod{\!125}.\,$ Then by $\,\rm\color{#90f}{BT}\,$ & $\, 65^{\large 3+k}\!\equiv 0\,$ by $\,5^{\large 3}\!\mid 65^{\large 3}\,$ so

$\qquad\ \ \ \begin{align} &8^{\large 8^8-2}\! = 8^{2N}\!\!= (-1\!+\!65)^N\!\equiv -1\! +\! N\cdot 65 - \tfrac{N(N-1)}2 65^2\equiv \color{#c00}{-21}\!\!\!\pmod{\!125}\\[.2em]
\Rightarrow\ &8^{\large 8^8-1}\! \equiv 8(\color{#c00}{-21})\equiv \color{#0a0}{82}\!\pmod{\!125}\\[.2em]
\Rightarrow\ &8^{\large 8^8}\!\!\equiv 8(\color{#0a0}{82})\equiv  \bbox[5px,border:1px solid #c00]{656}\!\!\!\pmod{\!8\cdot 125}
\end{align}$

**Stronger** $\,8^{\large 8^8}\!\!\equiv 6656\pmod{\!8000}\,$ if we use $\!\bmod 1000$ in 2nd last congruence.

Generally the most efficient way to handle problems like this is to employ the extremely handy mDL = **$\!\bmod\!\!$ Distributive Law** as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3161162/242) to greatly decrease the modulus. Applying this law here we can pull out a factor of $\,\color{#e0f}{a = 8}\,$ from the modulus as follows
$\begin{align} 
ab\,\bmod\, ac \,&=\, \color{#e0f}a(b\, \bmod\, c)^{\phantom{|^|}}\!\!\!\ \ \ \ [\!\bmod\text{Distributive Law}]\\[.1em]
\Longrightarrow\ 8^{\large 2+2N}\! \bmod 1000 \,&=\, \color{#e0f}8(8^{\large 1+2N}\! \qquad\,\ \bmod 125)\\
 &=\, 8(8(-1\!+\!65)^N\! \bmod 125)\\
 &=\, 8(8(\color{#a00}{-21})\qquad\bmod{125})\ \ \ {\rm by} \ \ {\rm \color{#90f}{BT}\ as\ above,\ and}\,\ N\equiv -18\\
 &=\, 8(\color{#0a0}{82})= 656_{\phantom{|_{|_|}}}
\end{align}$
**Explanation:** first we used mDL to factor out $\,\color{#e0f}{a=8}\,$ from the $\!\bmod\!$ to simplify the problem by reducing the modulus from $\,8\cdot 125\,$ to $\,125.\,$ So we have reduced to  powering $8$ modulo $125$. By luck $\,8^{\large 2}\equiv -1\!+\!65\equiv  -1\pmod{\!5}$ which we can lift up to $\!\bmod 5^{\large 3}$ by the Binomial Theorem, after writing $\,8^{\large 1+2N}\! = 8(8^2)^N\! = 8(-1\!+\!65)^N,\,$ leaving only simple mod arithmetic to finish.

Comment: May I ask why $N := (8^8 - 2) / 2$ is chosen?

Comment: @LearningMathematics I added an explanation, using mDL to clarify the operations (this is the best way in general - compare the two approaches). Note $\,K = \color{#c00}2+\color{#0a0}2N\iff N = (K-2)/2.\,$ In OP $\,K = 8^8\,$ is our exponent. The red $\,\color{#c00}2\,$ corresponds to the two factors of $8$ we pull out, and the green $\,\color{#0a0}2\,$ comes from needing to square $\,8\,$ to get a to a simple form enabling us to easily lift powering from $\!\bmod 5\,$ up to $\bmod 5^3\,$ by the Binomial Theorem.

Comment: Typo: "get a to a simple" should be "get to a..."

Answer (score 0):

$1000=8\cdot 125$, so $\phi(1000)=4\cdot4\cdot25=400$, $8^8\mod 400 = 16$. Then $8^{16}\mod 1000=656$. So the answer is $656$.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without the totient function? I'll be explaining this problem to a bunch of high schoolers who don't really have a background in number theory.

Comment: Considering the fact that $8^{8^8}$ is clearly congruent to $0$ modulo $8$, we can get away with $\phi(125)=100$ instead. You quickly get the same result, though.

Comment: @KingLogic For the last digit, and possibly for the last two digits, you can likely just look at $8^n$, see a repeating pattern, use that pattern. For the last three digits, though, that approach feels like it's too much work to be worthwhile. I don't think there are other, easier approaches either.

Comment: @JCAA I realize that, but it is for people who have extremely little background on number theory, and I don't want to have to spend a couple minutes explaining the totient function to them, and then they bombard me with many questions, taking forever.

Comment: @KingLogic Then maybe this exercise isn't for them. Consider asking about only the final digit instead.

Comment: @Arthur maybe you're right.

Comment: The question (including first version) *explicitly* asks for answers without using totient, so this is not an answer.

Comment: @JCAA I have upvoted your answer, but because I desire an answer without the totient, I have decided to withhold the acceptance checkmark.

Comment: OP said, " I would like to keep the explanation as basic as possible, without such devices as Euler's totient function, etc."

Comment: @JCAA You need to read more carefully - see the final paragraph of the question. Also your aswer still leaves a lot of work (exponentiation) to be performed, much of which would likely be nontrivial *to beginners*.

Comment: @JCAA By that logic they could also (painfully) compute $8^{8^8}$ by multipolication tables too. The point is that there are more intelligent ways using number theory to make the calculations (much) quicker and less painful (and also illustrate interesting number theory along the way).

Comment: For the record: JCAA has deleted his comments that the prior three comments were in reply to.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment the OP stated

> I would like an extremely elementary method, to teach to high school
> students with very little background in number theory.

To begin observe that

$$ 8^{8^8} = 8^{2^{24}}$$

So starting with $8$ we need to apply the squaring operation $24$ times. Moreover, at each step we only need to keep track of the last $3$ digits since the other digits in the base-$10$ expansion can't have an impact on them when squaring the numbers.

To save work we decide to find a more general squaring rule that can hopefully be reused. We'll use the formula

$ (s+t)^2 = s^2 + 2st + t^2$

on the base-$10$ expansions to get our rules.

The $\equiv$ symbol will mean that two numbers have the same last $3$ digits.

To square $8$ and get the last $3$ digits observe, where $0 \le a \le 9$, that

$\; \text{Rule08:} (a10^2 +08)^2 \equiv \quad 600a +64$

So

$\tag 1 8^2 \equiv 64$

Continuing

$\; \text{Rule64:} (a10^2 +64)^2 \equiv \quad 800a +96$
$\tag 2 {64}^2 \equiv 96$
$\; \text{Rule96:} (a10^2 +96)^2 \equiv \quad 200(a+1) + 16$
$\tag 3 {96}^2 \equiv 216$
$\; \text{Rule16:} (a10^2 +16)^2 \equiv \quad 200(a+1) + 56$
$\tag 4 {216}^2 \equiv 656$
$\; \text{Rule56:} (a10^2 +56)^2 \equiv \quad 200a+100 + 36$
$\tag 5 {656}^2 \equiv 336$
$\; \text{Rule36:} (a10^2 +36)^2 \equiv \quad 200(a+1) + 96$
$\tag 6 {336}^2 \equiv 896$

We are happy to see that we can repeatedly apply the four rules

$$ \text{Rule96} \mapsto \text{Rule16} \mapsto \text{Rule56} \mapsto \text{Rule36} \mapsto \dots $$

in a cycle; the following is all mental work.

$\tag 7 {896}^2 \equiv 816$
$\tag 8 {816}^2 \equiv 856$
$\tag 9 {856}^2 \equiv 736$
$\tag {10} {736}^2 \equiv 696$
$\tag {11} {696}^2 \equiv 416$
$\tag {12} {416}^2 \equiv 056$
$\tag {13} {056}^2 \equiv 136$
$\tag {14} {136}^2 \equiv 496$
$\tag {15} {496}^2 \equiv 016$
$\tag {16} {016}^2 \equiv 256$
$\tag {17} {256}^2 \equiv 536$
$\tag {18} {536}^2 \equiv 296$
$\tag {19} {296}^2 \equiv 616$
$\tag {20} {616}^2 \equiv 456$
$\tag {21} {456}^2 \equiv 936$
$\tag {22} {936}^2 \equiv 096$
$\tag {23} {096}^2 \equiv 216$
$\tag {24} {216}^2 \equiv 656$

Observe that $8^{2^{22}} \equiv  8^{2^2} \equiv 096$ so the squaring sequence was just starting to repeat - the last two rule based calculations were not necessary.