# How to compute $\,3^{3^{3^{\:\!\phantom{}^{.^{.^.}}}}}\!\!\!\!\bmod 46,$ for power tower height $2020$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, tetration, power-towers

What is the remainder of $\,3^{3^{3^{\:\!\phantom{}^{.^{.^.}}}}}\!\!\!$ divided by $46$?  The level of powers is $2020$.

First there is no parenthesis so it means 3 power of 3 which is also power 3 and so on 2020 times

Second I think that we can use Fermat's Little Theorem but I don't know how, and maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Note that $a^{(b^c)}\neq (a^b)^c$ in general, so your expression is ambiguous.

Comment: assume it's right associative @ArturoMagidin

Comment: No, Fermat's little theorem isn't going to work, at least not by itself, because $46$ is not a prime. There are ways to fix this, however.

Comment: any other ideas ?

Comment: @SakethMalyala: Don’t you think you should let the OP answer?

Comment: $46=23\cdot 2$. Use Chinese remainder theorem

Comment: would you explain more please

Comment: You can describe this number with the notation for teration $$3\uparrow \uparrow 2020$$ which is a power tower consisting of $2020$ $3's$.

Comment: @Peter That argument is not correct. See my answer for the correct result.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin That's not really a matter of opinion, $a^{b^c}=a^{(b^c)}$ is simply the most common convention, especially since $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$ can already be written more simply as such.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt It is not so rigorously however as , for example , the convention for the square-root. That said, in the context of power towers the purpose is usually to produce huge numbers, which only works if we assume that they are calculated from above.

Comment: @Peter I've no idea what you mean by rigorous here, but I've never seen $a^{b^c}$ mean $(a^b)^c$ in any context, as having $a^{b\widehat~c}=a^{b\times c}$ is simply confusing at best.

Answer (score 1):

We can easily apply [Euler's totient theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) here several times

$\varphi(46)=\varphi(2)\varphi(23)=22$

$\varphi(22)=\varphi(2)\varphi(11)=10$

$\varphi(10)=\varphi(2)\varphi(5)=4$

$\varphi(4)=2$

$\varphi(2)=1$

since they are all coprime to $3$. This gives the result:

\begin{align}R&=3\widehat~(3\widehat~(3\widehat~(3\widehat~(3\widehat~n))))\bmod46\\&=3\widehat~(3\widehat~(3\widehat~(3\widehat~(3\widehat~(n\bmod1)\bmod2)\bmod4)\bmod10)\bmod22)\bmod46\\&=3\widehat~(3\widehat~(3\widehat~(3\widehat~(3\widehat~1\bmod2)\bmod4)\bmod10)\bmod22)\bmod46\\&=3\widehat~(3\widehat~(3\widehat~(3\widehat~1\bmod4)\bmod10)\bmod22)\bmod46\\&=3\widehat~(3\widehat~(3\widehat~3\bmod10)\bmod22)\bmod46\\&=3\widehat~(3\widehat~7\bmod22)\bmod46\\&=3\widehat~9\bmod46\\&=41\end{align}

for any value of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Power tower mods are all resolvable by iteratively applying MOR = [modular order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242).

$\!\!\bmod 23\!:\,\ 3^{\large 11}\!\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, 3^{\Large 3^{\Large 3^{\Large 3^n}}}\!\!\!\!\!\! \equiv 3^{\Large\color{#c00}{3^{\Large 3^{\Large 3^n}}\!\!\!\!\bmod 11}}\!\equiv 3^{\large\color{#c00}9}\equiv 18\ $ by MOR, by

$\!\!\color{#c00}{\bmod 11}\!:\,\ \ 3^{\large 5}\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#c00}{3^{\Large 3^{\Large 3^n}}}\!\!\equiv 3^{\Large\color{#0a0}{3^{\Large 3^n}\!\bmod 5}}\equiv 3^{\large\color{#0a0}2}\equiv\color{#c00}9\, $ by ditto,  by

$\!\!\color{#0a0}{\bmod 5}\!:\ \ \ \ \ 3^{\large 4}\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\ \color{#0a0}{3^{\Large 3^n}}\!\equiv\ 3^{\Large 3^n\bmod 4}\equiv 3^{\large 3}\equiv\color{#0a0}2,\ \ {\rm by}\ \bmod 4\!:\! \smash{\overbrace{3^n \equiv 3}^{\!\!\large (-1)^{\Large n}\, \equiv\ -1}}\!\!\!,\ {\rm by}\ n\ \rm odd$

Hence $\,n\,$ odd $\,\Rightarrow\, x:= 3^\smash{\Large 3^{\Large 3^{{\Large 3^n}}}}\!\!\!\!\!\equiv 18\pmod{\!23},\,$ so $\,x\,$ odd $\Rightarrow\, x\equiv 18\!+\!23\equiv 41\pmod{\!46}$

For $\,n\,$ even we get $\, \color{#0a0}{3\pmod{\! 5}},\,$ so $\,3^{\large \color{#0a0}3}\equiv\color{#c00}{5\pmod{\! 11}},\:$ so $\,\ x\equiv 3^{\large\color{#c00}5}\equiv 13\pmod{\!23\ \&\ 46}$

Hence, more generally $\,\ \bbox[1px,border:1px solid #0a0]{\bbox[8px,border:1px solid #050]{\!\!\bmod 46\!:\,\ 3^{\Large 3^{\Large 3^{{\Large 3^n}}}}\!\!\!\equiv\, \left\{\begin{align} &41,\ \,n\,\ \rm odd\\ &13,\ \,n\,\ \rm even\end{align}\right.}}$

Comment: We used $ \bmod 23\!:\, \left[3\equiv 7^{\large 2}\right]^{\large 11}\!\!\Rightarrow\, 3^{\large 11}\equiv 7^{\large 22}\equiv 1.\,$ Similarly $\!\color{#c00}{\bmod 11}\,$ using $\,3\equiv 6^2\ \ $

Comment: **Note** $ $ The same method works for any height power towers, but we may need to additionally apply the mod distributive law (or CRT) when the base is not coprime to the modulus, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3212901/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3161162/242)