# Do modular rules apply for repeated exponents

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

The exponent rule for modular arithmetic states that $$a^b \equiv (a \;mod \; m)^b \;(mod\;m)$$

Does this rule apply for repeated exponents which are computed from top to bottom?
For example, is this true?
$$a^{b^c} \equiv (a\;mod\;m)^{(b\;mod\;m)^c}\;(mod\;m)$$

Comment: Euler's theorem says exponents work mod $\varphi(n)$ when you work mod $n$ in the base.

Comment: No, in exponents you need to apply [modular order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242)

Comment: e.g. $\large \bmod p\!:\ a \equiv a^p \not\equiv a^0\,$ generally.

Comment: Due to the first statement and because exponentiation starts from top
$$b^c \equiv (b \;mod \; m)^c \;(mod\;m)$$
therefore the second statement should be
$$a^{b^c} \equiv (a\;mod\;m)^{(b \;mod \; m)^c \;(mod\;m)}\;(mod\;m)$$
I guess.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3558102/242) for one of many prior answers on power tower modular reductions.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó That is not correct.